# php - how to get specific value from the string

Tags: php, string, preg-match-all

I am facing issue when trying to extract specific value from the string but not getting the proper output.

```
$string = com.xyz.ghop.service.sprint.Sprint@1b0258c[id=257,rapidViewId=94,state=CLOSED,name=Alert Success 5,goal=,startDate=2016-08-16T20:20:46.730+05:30,endDate=2016-08-26T20:20:00.000+05:30,completeDate=2016-08-26T21:18:53.928+05:30,sequence=257]
```

I want the value inside name= till the comma and I tried with preg_match_all but it just gives the first word.

This is what I tried:

```
preg_match_all("/(?=name\=([^\W]+))/", $string, $matches); 
$resulte = implode(",", $matches[1]);
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you tried with `preg_match`?

Comment: preg_match_all("/(?=name\=([^\W]+))/", $string, $matches); $resulte = implode(",", $matches[1]);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are multiple approaches , available on whether preg_match or preg_match_all

```
$results = preg_match('#name=(.*?),#', $matches);
```

OR

```
$results = preg_match('#name=([^,]+),#', $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks.Cant it return just the value rather "name=Alert Success 5" just "Alert Success 5"

Comment: @Areik access `$matches[1]` for that

Comment: as @sidyll said , by the way i've updated the answer

Comment: @HassanAhmed now you made the opposite of what he asked :D

Comment: :D but it will fit with the original question

Comment: but when I access $matches[0] I am getting output like this "name=Alert Success 5,"

Comment: i didn't know what you are exactly want, the current pattern will return only value `Alert Success 5` when you are use `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like:

```
preg_match("/name=(.+?),/", $string, $matches);
$result = end($matches);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: why using end ! $matches[1]; is enough as long as you are matching one thing .

Comment: @HassanAhmed Why not... :)